# Can constant symbols (or functions) be introduced in standard translation of modal logic?

Tags: first-order-logic, modal-logic

When translating modal logic to first-order logic, I notice that the translated structure in first-order logic does not have constant symbols. I am thinking about whether it is possible that the translated structure in first-order logic has some constant symbols.

Because the constant symbols can be equivalently replaced with a unary predicate, if the translated structure has a constant $c$, that constant can be replaced with a unary predicate $P(x,c)=:(x=c)$. Then the corresponding modal logic has an extra proposition $c$ and valuation $V(w) = \{ c \}$.

I want to know if what I think for constant symbols is correct or not. And if there is a function in a translated structure, does there exist a corresponding modal logic?

Answer (score 1):

I think that replacing constants with predicates is a bit more involved than you present. See, for example, here [is first-order logic with constants equally expressive as first-order logic without constants?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2860666/is-first-order-logic-with-constants-equally-expressive-as-first-order-logic-with)

Regarding the standard translation, your approach with equality is actually a part of standard translation of hybrid logic into a fragment of FOL with equality (without functions and constants).

There are some translations that have functions in their image. See, for example, first-order intensional modal logic http://cachescan.bcub.ro/e-book/V/580527_07.pdf

Comment: Thank you so much. I refer to another question [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2882223/converting-a-fol-formula-to-a-predicate-only-version](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2882223/converting-a-fol-formula-to-a-predicate-only-version). Instead of translating atomic formulas, it seems a sentence $\phi$ in my case can be translated to $(\exists ! y, y=c) \wedge \bar{\phi}$. Assume there is a constant $c$ in $\phi$, $\bar{\phi}$ is translated to $\phi(y) \wedge (y=c)$.

Comment: Besides, $\cdot = c$ is actually a unary predicate. I can rewrite $\cdot = x$ to $P_c(x)$, and its value is true when $x=c$ and false otherwise.